# how to assign function output to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to get the list that is outputted by the function and assign the list to a variable so i can use the len method on it but I don't know how

```
def count(list):
return ([i for item in list for i in item.split()])
```

list = [""]

Comment: Are yoi looking for len([.....]) ?

Comment: It's just `x = count(your_list)`. I suggest reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: FYI you shouldn’t use a variable name like `list` Because it overrides the builtin type `list`. Yes I know it’s a pain because in particular how could a beginner know that? I find it helps to add an s to variables that are a list - you might use the name `items` and then use the singular `item` when doing e.g. `for item in items:`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
def count(item_list):
    return ([i for item in item_list for i in item.split()])

list_returned_by_count = count(item_list)
```

Then, you can use the len method on it.

```
len(list_returned_by_count)
```